# What is the term for a structure, unconnected to the main building, on an estate?

Tags: single-word-requests

For a large property, or estate, what is the term for buildings other than the main residence that are separate and unconnected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider *outbuilding*, *dependency*, *annex*, and *lodge*.

> [outbuilding](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/outbuilding), (chiefly BrE) [outhouse](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/outhouse?s=t): a detached building 
>   subordinate to a main building
>
> [dependency](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dependency): outbuilding; annex
>
> [annex](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Annex): a building added on to a larger one or an auxiliary building situated near a main one.
>
> [lodge](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lodge): a house on an estate originally for the use of a gamekeeper, caretaker, or porter

Comment: Annex is a building built next to another and attached, lodge is a type of building and would normally be the main building, and outbuilding is an old term for shed.

Comment: "Outbuilding" perhaps, but please lets not confuse that with an "outhouse"...

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd FYI RyeBread, the main building on a large property or estate is not called "lodge" but "mansion." A lodge is usually found near a property's gate.

Comment: In the UK, the word "outhouses" would in fact be the correct answer.

Comment: @Rupe I'll make an edit to point that out.

Answer (score 2):

Usually called a **guest house** in the US.

Now there are also several terms depending on what you need.  The term **detached** is used formally.  A detached garage.  A detached guest house/quarters.

There is also the **outhouse** for those still with outdoor toilets.

**Cabana** next to the pool.

**Shed** that houses your outdoor tools.

Comment: @RyeBread An annex is not necessarily attached to the main building. In addition, an outhouse is usually a small outdoor building used as a toilet and formerly called "privy." http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/outhouse